# MDB file behind a Microsoft Access Runtime application

Tags: ms-access-2010

How can I open mdb file behind an Access Runtime Application in Microsoft Access 2010?

When I open the Access Runtime Application, it never shows the database objects like tables, forms and reports.

Comment: When using the full Access version to examine the Access options for Current Database, is there a startup form identified in the box labelled "Display Form"?

Comment: When I click on the file with accdr extension, it does not show any Access menu options, so I cannot check the startup form.

Comment: Make a copy of that file.  Change the file extension on that copy to accdb.  Open the accdb with a full version of Access, and then check the database options.

Comment: I did that but even now when I open it does not show the Access toolbar.

Comment: Sorry I don't have 64 bit Access, so can't open your db file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot open tables, etc from the Access Runtime. It is a partial version meant for viewing and working on already established projects from the administrator's database.
Stewie